# Elastic search (1.6) not starting on windows7 with jdk1.7.0_71

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to elastic search and when i start it ..keep getting below warning. can anybody help here..what need to to be changed.

```
[2015-06-25 13:04:15,143][WARN ][bootstrap                ] jvm uses the client vm, make sure to run `java` with the server vm for best performance by adding `-server` to the command line
    [2015-06-25 13:04:15,244][INFO ][node                     ] [Kubik] version[1.6.0], pid[20068], build[cdd3ac4/2015-06-09T13:36:34Z]
    [2015-06-25 13:04:15,244][INFO ][node                     ] [Kubik] initializing ...
    [2015-06-25 13:04:15,247][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Kubik] loaded [], sites []
    [2015-06-25 13:04:15,277][INFO ][env                      ] [Kubik] using [1] data paths, mounts [[System (C:)]], net usable_space [109.3gb], net total_space [238.1gb], types [NTFS]
    [2015-06-25 13:04:18,034][INFO ][node                     ] [Kubik] initialized
    [2015-06-25 13:04:18,034][INFO ][node                     ] [Kubik] starting ...
    [2015-06-25 13:04:18,317][INFO ][transport                ] [Kubik] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9300]}, publish_address {inet[/10.154.249.29:9300]}
    [2015-06-25 13:04:18,669][INFO ][discovery                ] [Kubik] elasticsearch/ZWZR28dARWqqEf8FOn0Hgw
    [2015-06-25 13:04:18,688][WARN ][transport.netty          ] [Kubik] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0xdfa8e460]], closing connection
    java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: no further information
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.connect(NioClientBoss.java:152)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.processSelectedKeys(NioClientBoss.java:105)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.process(NioClientBoss.java:79)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.run(NioClientBoss.java:42)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: try with java latest version

Comment: Resolved my issue ....go to config/elasticsearch.yaml and modify 'network.host' property with 127.0.0.1

Comment: @gurdeep.sabarwal can you please add your comment as answer and accept? Will be helpful for others to find

Comment: @dubes  sure ...will do that.. thx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Resolved my issue.... putting this as Answer so that it will be helpful for others.

go to installed ElasticSearch setup and go to folder **"config"** and then file ***"elasticsearch.yml"*** and add/modify *'network.host'* property with *"127.0.0.1"* .